# Angular 12 Datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, datepicker, angular12

I am trying to use material datepicker in Angular 12, but having error:

**main.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeChanges' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'localeChanges' of null**

Any suggestion about other datepicker working fine on angular 12?

Comment: You might want to try angular-mydatepicker by kekeh

Comment: Please provide your code so that others can determine the problem.

Answer (score 35):

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';

....

imports: [
   MatInputModule,
   MatDatepickerModule,
   MatNativeDateModule
]
```

import these two in your app.module.ts

The order matters here, `MatInputModule` should be imported before `MatDatepickerModule`.

Comment: Could you add documentation citations on why these dependencies are required?

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This fixed my problem. And they still did not add it to the documentaion.